# Visa processing speed: VFS vs Embassy

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland, embassies

I am applying for a Schengen Visa for Switzerland at London. To submit my application, I can choose to go to the VFS Visa Application Centre or the Embassy of Switzerland directly. I wonder which option would result in getting back my passport faster.

I know that the VFS Centre will deliver my application to the Embassy by the end of the day of my appointment, which means this method will be one day slower than going to the Embassy. However, the VFS Centre can return my passport using a courier, while the Embassy will only use regular postal service. If I collect in person, at VFS I can collect on the same day when my visa is processed, but at the Embassy I can only collect on the next day because the Embassy is only open in the morning.

So which way do you recommend if time is my top concern?

Comment: @GayotFow Did you mean VFS? But the VFS Centre for Switzerland is at 66 Wilson Street. I've been to the Paddington Centre a couple of times for other visas, but I didn't know that Swiss Visa is at another place.

Answer (score 2):

If time is your top concern you would use the VFS at Paddington Station or the VFS at 66 Wilson Street.  Although they will not deliver your application until close of business following your appointment you can pick up your passport at the VFS without having to queue at the Swiss Embassy.

Logistically, Paddington Station is better connected to the tube and 66 Wilson Street is a 10 minute walk from Liverpool Street Station, which connects all the major tube lines.  The Swiss Embassy, on the other hand, is inside Marylebone and the nearest tube stop is Edgware Road.  It's also a 10 minute walk, but as mentioned above you face queues.

In the absence of all other information, you're better off nearer to a major train station and have the opportunity to collect your passport on the same day (or sent by courier).